# is this an error in bootstrap?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Just curious.. I was going through the code bootstrap.css and saw the following..

```
.container {
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-left: auto;
}

.container:before,
.container:after {
  display: table;
  content: " ";
}

.container:after {
  clear: both;
}

.container:before,
.container:after {
  display: table;
  content: " ";
}

.container:after {
  clear: both;
}
```

It seems that a portion of the code is repeating and does the same thing... even if you take it out of the css code specifically the following:

```
.container:before,
    .container:after {
      display: table;
      content: " ";
    }

    .container:after {
      clear: both;
    }
```

it seems that all works fine and dandy.

Is it an error or oversight?

Comment: Who knows? Perhaps the developers at Twitter could help you.

Comment: No need to be rude. just was asking a question to this awesome community

Comment: Wasn't trying to be rude - just pointing you at someone who might know.

Comment: that wasn't *rude* at **all**...

Comment: It's a clearfix: http://nicolasgallagher.com/micro-clearfix-hack/. Removing it will probably only impact layouts which need it (and probably only under certain conditions, e.g. depending on content). The repetition could be an error, albeit a harmless one.

Comment: Yes, it is the clear fix, but the same code as you can see in the first box is repeated twice.

the first section is copied directly from bootstrap.css file

Comment: Report it as a bug to the bootstrap guys and the response to that will a: fix it if it is a bug and b: let you know :) Unless one of us happens to be a Twitter developer we are unlikely to be able to give a real answer....

Answer (score 2):

It was a bug, but was [fixed](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/commit/0016c17f9307bc71fc96d8d4680a9c861f137cae) a month ago.  There is some debate on whether it was a Bootstrap bug, or a bug in their CSS compiler, LESS.  Discussion on bugtrackers for [LESS](https://github.com/less/less.js/issues/1437), [Bootstrap](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/issues/8947).

### Details

Bootstrap CSS is compiled from [Less](http://lesscss.org/), and this particular section of the code comes from [grid.less](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/blob/master/less/grid.less), using mixins from [mixins.less](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/blob/master/less/mixins.less).

Figuring out why it's duplicating requires going down a couple layers.  The relevant Less code is here:

```
// Set the container width, and override it for fixed navbars in media queries
.container {
  .container-fixed();

  @media (min-width: @screen-sm) {
    width: @container-sm;
  }
  @media (min-width: @screen-md) {
    width: @container-md;
  }
  @media (min-width: @screen-lg-min) {
    width: @container-lg;
  }
}
```

Which uses the mixin `.container-fixed()`:

```
// Centered container element
.container-fixed() {
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-left: auto;
  padding-left:  (@grid-gutter-width / 2);
  padding-right: (@grid-gutter-width / 2);
  .clearfix();
}
```

Which in turn uses the mixin `.clearfix()`:

```
.clearfix() {
  &:before,
  &:after {
    content: " "; // 1
    display: table; // 2
  }
  &:after {
    clear: both;
  }
}
```

**EDIT:** After some further digging, the bug was that they had inadvertently defined the .clearfix() macro twice - once in [mixins.less](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/blob/master/less/mixins.less#L19) and then again in [utilities.less](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/blob/master/less/utilities.less#L9).  You can see it in action at [less2css.org](http://less2css.org/) with this LESS code:

```
.clearfix() {
  &:before,
  &:after {
    content: " "; // 1
    display: table; // 2
  }
  &:after {
    clear: both;
  }
}

.container {
   .clearfix();
}

.clearfix {
  .clearfix();
}
```

I don't know enough LESS to say for sure, but it seems that the second .clearfix is being treated as some sort of mixin, and is looping.  If you switch the LESS version ("Options" button at less2css.org) to 1.3.1 or earlier, you get a recursion error - it seems LESS added some code to stop the infinite recursion, but some duplicates still get generated.

Further notes: this bug affected everything that had a .clearfix() mixin - I say that in past tense, because they recently [fixed this bug](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/commit/0016c17f9307bc71fc96d8d4680a9c861f137cae), namely by switching to a different way of using the mixins.

**TL;DR**: Yes, it was a bug, but they [fixed it](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/commit/0016c17f9307bc71fc96d8d4680a9c861f137cae) a month ago.  There is some discussion of whether it was a LESS bug or a Bootstrap bug on [LESS's bugtracker](https://github.com/less/less.js/issues/1437) and back over on [Bootstrap](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/issues/8947).

Comment: Yeh on line 791 to 809 of the bootstrap.css file it repeats the same thing twice.. which is what i posted above..

Comment: Right, but my point is nobody actually writes the bootstrap.css file.  That's generated by LESS, so the bug is one level up, so to speak.

Comment: @cincodenada - Has this been fixed?  Because I have downloaded the latest source code from Bootstrap v3.1.1 and it is still defined twice in mixins.less and utilities.less.  Compiling using lessc latest version (v1.7) still outputs duplicate code for clearfix when importing bootstrap.less by reference